# maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have this repository in my `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I'm trying to built an application I got an error like this:

```
im@im:~/projects/nsn_maintenance_be/maintenance$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maintenance 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for javax.xml.crypto:xmldsig:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.770 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-22T19:09:32+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/211M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project maintenance: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ia:maintenance:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find javax.xml.crypto:xmldsig:jar:1.0 in http://maven.springframework.org/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-maven-release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I'm a bit confused by this error and not sure what I should do because I can see this lib in my local repository:

[image]

Comment: Try to delete .m2 directory and run once again and check.

Answer (score 0):

I think maven indeed doesn't recognize the pom. 
In regular cases the jar and pom should reside in the corresponding folder in your local repository without any suffix (like 'lastUpdated' in the presented snippet).

Try to remove the folder `~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0` altogether and run the maven. The chances are that it will bring the jar and the pom again and won't fail this time (you can back up instead of deletion of course outside the repositoy, just a side note :) )

Comment: I deleted `~/.m2/repository/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0` but after `mvn clean install` it appears again. May be I have to use some another maven command?

Answer (score 0):

xmldsig is not available in the repository you have configured.

Just remove the whole "repositories" section, you should point by default to Maven central which has all the libraries of http://maven.springframework.org/release plus all the libraires required to build your project.

Comment: "Just remove the whole "repositories" section" ... should I add some specific repository to get  "default Maven central"?

Comment: No, Maven central is configured by default if no repositories section is defined in your pom.

Comment: Still getting almost the same error but with another url of pero: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project maintenance: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.nokia:maintenance:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find javax.xml.crypto:xmldsig:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,`

Comment: right I missed that the first time but xmldsig is under parentId javax.xml and not javax.xml.crypto. If it is directly in your pom, just change, if is is not, please post your pom.